# counterexample to conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let F,G be some $\sigma-algebra$ is it true that in general

$E\left(E\left(X\mid G\right)\mid F\right)\neq E\left(X\mid F\cap G\right)$?

I think it's not, however I can't provide a counter example

Comment: Here's a suggestion: When finding a counterexample, you have to choose the $\sigma$-algebras $F$ and $G$ such that neither is contained in the other, i.e. $F\not\subseteq G$, and $G\not\subseteq F$. Otherwise the two expressions will be equal.

Comment: Consider the random variable $X=0$ always.  Then all expectations and conditional expectations of $X$ are 0.  So, this is a trivial counter-example to show your inequality does not always hold.  In this case, equality obviously _does_ hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$, three atoms each of probability $1/3$.

$X(a)=X(b)=0$, $X(c)=1$.

$\mathcal F = \big\{\Omega, \varnothing,\{a,b\}, \{c\}\big\}$

$\mathcal G = \big\{\Omega,\varnothing,\{a\}, \{b,c\}\big\}$.

Compute $E[E[X|\mathcal G]|\mathcal F]$: it has value $1/4$ at $a$ and $b$, value $1/2$ at $c$.

Complute $E[X|\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G]$: it is the constant $1/3$.

**added remark**

Define sequence $X_0=X$, $X_{2n+1} = E[X_{2n}|\mathcal F]$, $X_{2n+2} = E[X_{2n+1}|\mathcal G]$.  Then can you show that sequence $X_n$ converges (in some appropriate sense) to $E[X|\mathcal F \cap \mathcal G]$ ??